# Exporting the JSON from an API in Python

Tags: python, json, api

Currently I have managed to connect to a public API and got a JSON back (a massive JSON) and I managed to get into the python console into something translatable:

```
import requests
import json
import sys
response = requests.get("http://api.gipod.vlaanderen.be/ws/v1/workassignment")
def jprint(obj):
    # create a formatted string of the Python JSON object
    text = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    print(text)
print(response.status_code)
jprint(response.json())
```

Here is an example of response I can get:

**Not this is only one off the objects, the amount object I get can be over 100.**

```
[
{
"gipodId": 103246,
"owner": "Eandis Leuven",
"description": ", , ZAVELSTRAAT: E Nieuw distributienet (1214m)",
"startDateTime": "2007-12-03T06:00:00",
"endDateTime": "2014-01-06T19:00:00",
"importantHindrance": false,
"coordinate": {
"coordinates": [
4.697028256276443,
50.896894135898485
],
"type": "Point",
"crs": {
"type": "name",
"properties": {
"name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
}
}
},
"detail": http://api.gipod.vlaanderen.be/ws/v1/workassignment/103246?crs=4326,
"cities": ["Leuven"]
}
],
"latestUpdate": "2016-11-16T11:32:39.253"
}
```

However one problem that I have is that I cannot really find a good tutorial about exporting this requested JSON to a file, even something like getting a file dialog to save the file to a certain location.

So can anyone help me for this? All tutorials so far, have shown me that I need to define the "columns" so to speak, but is there really nothing simpler? I need to get all the fields for now because of the Coordinate data.

Edit 1: Thanks to furas I am bit further in my programming, but this is actually still not solved because I do not get directory where it gets saved.

```
import requests

import json

import sys

response = requests.get("http://api.gipod.vlaanderen.be/ws/v1/workassignment")
print(response.status_code)

text = json.dumps(response.json(),sort_keys=True, indent=4)
print(text)

f = open("text.json", "wt")
f.write(text)
```

Edit 2: update, yes the file has now been saved: but the location of the file should matter, technically this question is solved thanks to furgas, but setting up the file location by file dialog is still preferred.

```
import requests

import json

import sys

import os

import geojson



response = requests.get("http://api.gipod.vlaanderen.be/ws/v1/workassignment", params = {"CRS": "Lambert72"})

print(response.status_code)
text = json.dumps(response.json(),sort_keys=True, indent=4)
print(text)

f = open("text.json", "wt")
f.write(text)

print(os.getcwd())
```

Comment: Do you want to save the text as a JSON file on your filesystem, or as a different file type altogether? If it's the former, simply using `with open('text.json', 'w') as f: f.write(text)` should do the trick.

Comment: The former yes, save as a JSON file. though I get some unexpected token 'as' error, doing this in Python 3.7 btw.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: using `response.json()` and later `json.dumps()` you convert `JSON string` to `python dictionary` and late back to `JSON string`. To save it you can directly save `response.text` in text file (mode `"w"`) or `response.content` in bytes file (mode `"wb"`)

Comment: as for `file dialog`: you have to choose GUI framework - `tkinter`, `PyQt`, `PyGTK`, `wxPython` and write code for `file dialog` (if it doesn't have prebuild `file dialog`). There is no one-line code for  `file dialog`. Even `tkinter` which have `asksavefilename` needs few lines for this.

Comment: But where does it get saved? Also I am not intrested in saving this in text file because the JSON is actually a GeoJSON (or supposed to be one) that you get back from the api.

Comment: `"JSON file"` is `"text file"` and you need only `f = open("filename.json", "w")` and `f.write(response.text)` to save it.

Comment: and `GeoJSON` is only `JSON file` with some Geo Data - so it is also `"text file"`

Comment: ..okay but where does it get saved? I will add the new code in the post. As an edit.

Comment: As you haven’t specified any path when opening the file to write, it will be in the current directory. You can print this using e.g. `print( os.getcwd() )`

Comment: print( os.getcwd() ) does not seem to work but it is fine for now. Can you give some pointers for setting up a filepath? Just a small prompt/gui to set up an filepath. Get it to save at one location at least to process it.

Comment: add `import os` to your code above. Look for `os.path.join()` in the documentation as a platform-independent way to construct a path. Don't be tempted to use `os.chdir()` because it can confuse the user unless you previously save `os.getcwd()` and then afterwards use `os.chdir()` to restore the original current directory. Search the Python documentation for these.